# Отменить переход по ссылке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет, есть вообщем ссылка:

```
<a href="http://google.ru" onclick="return myFunc('123', 'abx')">Click</a>
```

Есть функция в javascript:

```
var myFunc = function() { 
   $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "",
                            data: {
                                id: id,
                                updated_at: updated_at
                            },
                            success: function (result) {
                                if(result == 'ok') {
                                    return true;
                                } else {
                                    alert('error');
                                    return false;
                                }
                            }
                    });
}
```

Мне нужно отменить нажатие ссылки, если ajax вернул alert('error'). 
`return false` не помогает.
Что можно в этом случае сделать?

Comment: В блоке `if (result == 'ok')` либо осуществлять непосредственно переход на _http://google.ru_, либо триггерить клик по ссылке (а чтобы это не зациклилось, использовать флаг).

Comment: @Regent мне нужно, чтобы ссылка оставалась такой какая она есть и человек мог ее открывать в другой вкладке или просто, нужно просто отменить эвент, а как это сделать, хз

Comment: Вы решение принимает асинхронно, так что это ни разу не "просто". Вам в любом случае придётся блокировать первое событие клика и в случае успеха Ajax-запроса либо генерировать второе, либо просто выполнять нужное действие.

Comment: Можно, конечно, сделать синхронный Ajax-запрос, но за такое стоит расстреливать. А `return` в функции `success` будет бесполезен от слова "полностью".

Answer (score 0):

Так как решение принимается асинхронно, то придётся блокировать первый запрос и в случае успеха Ajax-запроса генерировать второй или переходить по URL-у с помощью JS.

Пример реализации с генерацией второго события и использованием флага:

```js
var $link = $("a");
var clickIsConfirmed = false;
var result = 0; //для примера

$link.on("click", function() {
  if (!clickIsConfirmed) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "",
      error: function() { //для примера
        result++; //для примера
        if (result == 2) { //для примера
          clickIsConfirmed = true;
          $link[0].click();
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">Click</a>
```

Пример реализации с переходом с помощью JS:

```js
var $link = $("a");
var result = 0; //для примера

$link.on("click", function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    error: function() { //для примера
      result++; //для примера
      if (result == 2) { //для примера
        window.location.href = $link.attr("href");
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.ru">Click</a>
```

Comment: это не то вообще, у меня совсем иной пример...

Comment: @Kexer чем ваш пример отличается от моего?